# Running standalone MapReduce jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, scheduling

Are there any risk of running MapReduce jobs with the following command from an edge node as part of scheduling a series of jobs:

```
hadoop jar <jar_location> <job_name> -libjars <location of dependent jars> -D mapreduce.job.reduces=0 -D mapreduce.map.speculative=false <location of input data> <location for output>
```

Comment: What kind of "risk" are you thinking about?

Comment: mostly in terms of scheduling this as part of a workflow - will it use cluster resources sensibly? And also having to store the jars on the edge nodes in this way

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any risks if the dependencies between jobs with respect to scheduling, input/output folders, job execution status, etc are taken care in a shell script which has the implementation to trigger all the jobs as per your requirement.

Typically, they do this in a development environment if Oozie workflow is not yet designed.